# Spark does not show data residing in a hive table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I create the following table using Spark:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)], ["A", "B"])
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("hivedb.mwe")
```

Now, if I try to count the data within this table:

```py
> spark.sql("SELECT count(*) FROM hivedb.mwe").show()

+--------+
|count(1)|
+--------+
|       0|
+--------+
```

However, if I count the data using Hive (or Impala, which gives the same result)

```py
jdbc:hive2:...> SELECT count(*) FROM hivedb.mwe

+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 3    |
+------+--+
```

What might be going on here that spark does not seem to see the data within mwe?

As an addon, Spark knows perfectly about the table:

```py
> spark.sql("DESCRIBE hivedb.mwe").show()

+--------+---------+-------+
|col_name|data_type|comment|
+--------+---------+-------+
|       A|   bigint|   null|
|       B|   bigint|   null|
+--------+---------+-------+
```

---

Just for completeness:

- Spark version: v2.2.0.cloudera1
- hivedb is a hive database that has been created with non-Standard Location Parameter
- The cluster is
  fully kerberized
- HDFS contains:

  ```py
  [myuser@cluster~]$ hdfs dfs -ls /path/to/hivedb/mwe
  Found 3 items
  -rw-r--r--   3 myuser somegroup          0 2018-02-09 13:29 /path/to/hivedb/mwe/_SUCCESS
  -rw-r--r--   3 myuser somegroup          526 2018-02-09 13:29 /path/to/hivedb/mwe/part-00000-f1e79c0d-fca5-4a46-aa70-3651baa96a90-c000.snappy.parquet
  -rw-r--r--   3 myuser somegroup          545 2018-02-09 13:29 /path/to/hivedb/mwe/part-00001-f1e79c0d-fca5-4a46-aa70-3651baa96a90-c000.snappy.parquet
  ```

Comment: Is your sparksession is created with enableHivesupport. The dB name your are saving in spark and reading in hive looks different

Comment: Yes, hive support is enabled. The different looking table names were due to a typo I introduced when I created the example. I corrected the question.

Comment: I think the Bug is the Issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a Known issue in cloudera 2.2 it seems.

**https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/spark2/latest/topics/spark2_known_issues.html#SPARK-21994**

The Best alternative solutions are provided can you look into the above link and perform the work around and see the solution is possible.

These are Solutions

```
val options = Map("path" -> "/path/to/hdfs/directory/containing/table")
df.write.options(options).saveAsTable("db_name.table_name")

spark.sql("alter table db_name.table_name set SERDEPROPERTIES ('path'='hdfs://host.example.com:8020/warehouse/path/db_name.db/table_name')")
spark.catalog.refreshTable("db_name.table_name")
```